# SweetAlert2 doesn't display

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I am trying to implement SweetAlert2 in a web app and after checking the forums and the website, I do not see any errors in the code but there is no way to see the message

The page I'm testing it on contains a link  button that deletes a record from the database. The registry deletes it but the SweetAlert2 message does not appear

This page contains the following :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/sweetAlert.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

And in a link  that acts as a button I have the id id="btnConfirm"

```
<td><a id="btnConfirm" href="del_register.php?Del=<?php echo base64_encode($row['id_mov']); ?>&Page=<?php echo base64_encode('movimientos'); ?>" ><img src="../../../images/delete.png" alt="Borrar Registro" title="Borrar Registro"></td>
```

In the jscript.js file, I have the following:

```
A constant that creates the object with the same name as the id, the addEventListener event that calls the function when clicked.

const $btnConfirm = document.querySelector("#btnConfirm");
$btnConfirm.addEventListener("click", mgsDelete);
function mgsDelete() {
Swal.fire({
  title: "YOU ARE DELETING A RECORD",
  text: "¿Are you sure?",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,

  confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete",
  cancelButtonText: "No, Cancel",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false,
},
function (isConfirm) {
  if (isConfirm) {
    Swal.fire("Deleted", "The record has been deleted!!!");
  } else {
    Swal.fire("Cancelled", "The record has NOT been deleted!!!");
  }
});
}
```

As I say, the message does not appear and I don't know where else to look.

I would appreciate if someone can help me see where I have the problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: fyi, your `<a>` is missing a closing `</a>`

Comment: Your script file `jscript.js` should be placed after sweetalert script lines.

Comment: Also as you have anchor tag, the page will navigate to the url irrespective of you click on confirm or cancel. You should move your deletion logic in isConfirm callback.

Comment: Hi, @CodeThing, can you make me an example , plz. I dont understand what you mean. Sorry

Comment: Hi @brombeer I put the </a> tag and doesn't show the sweetalert

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are navigating (because of the anchor tag behaviour) to a different URL event before giving user a chance to select yes or no.

In order to fix the things up you should first make sure your own script should load **after sweetalert scripts** and **after the page html content** is loaded.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/sweetAlert.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/jscript.js"></script>
```

*Not sure why you have two sweetalert scripts here*

Next, as commented by brombeer, you are missing closing anchor tag. So you need to make sure it is closed.

Next, in your script you need to first prevent the default anchor action in the event listener callback.

Sweetalert gives us callback function with some information about what user did when he saw the popup. in our case we need whether or not he confirmed (isConfirmed). Based on that we need to navigate the user to proper url when the deletion actual takes place.

```
const $btnConfirm = document.querySelector("#btnConfirm");
$btnConfirm.addEventListener("click", mgsDelete);

function mgsDelete(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // preventing default anchor navigation
  const linkTarget = e.target.href;
  Swal.fire({
    title: "YOU ARE DELETING A RECORD",
    text: "¿Are you sure?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete",
    cancelButtonText: "No, Cancel",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false,
  }).then(({
    isConfirmed
  }) => {
    if (isConfirmed) {
      // The alerts defined here should be moved inside del_register.php page after records are deleted.
      Swal.fire("Deleted", "The record has been deleted!!!");
      window.location.href = linkTarget;
    } else {
      Swal.fire("Cancelled", "The record has NOT been deleted!!!");
    }
  });
}
```

I see you are showing alerts again after confirmation. In my opinion these should be defined once the actual deletion takes place. In presume that is inside `del_register.php` page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @CodeThing this does not work. It does not show any message.

I remove this line <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../js/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>, because is a copy of the one with the url.

If I write a simple sweetalert it show the message, but it doesn't give the opportunity to click any button cause dissapear fleetingly

Comment: Which alert you are not seeing. The one with confirm "YOU ARE DELETING A RECORD" or other alert "The record has been deleted!!!"?

Comment: Hi @codething it doesn't show anything

Comment: @joserodriguezan Make sure you have only one button with id `btnConfirm` on the page. as we have added `e.preventDefault()` it should stop the default anchor behaviour.

Comment: I can't understand the reason, but works fine with swal but not with swal.fire.
I have decided to create my own script. Thank you.